# How to get the numbers in a interval with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, numbers

I am looking for a way to get, using JavaScript, the numbers in a interval. For example, I could want to know what numbers are between 1-3, 4-8 or 12-15. Can I do that using JavaScript?

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: I am studying mathematics in JavaScript, and I need a formula to do this. I need to specifically do this.

Comment: inclusive? exclusive? how is the *input criteria* specified, as a string like `1-3`? use the string split method to access the range vlues

Comment: It is about numbers. For example, between 4 and 8 (4-8), there are the numbers 5, 6 and 7. But I need to get those numbers using Javascript.

Comment: so, exclusive, once you have the start and end numbers, a simple for loop will iterate through those numbers for you `for (var i = start + 1; i < end; ++i)`

Comment: the interval content an infinity irrational numbers, I don't think it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of attempts.

```
const interval = (x, y) => {
    let result = [];
    let i = x + 1;
    while (i < y) {
        result.push(i);
        i++;
    }
    return result;  
};

interval(1, 4) // [2, 3]
```

```
const intervalRecursive = (x, y, accum = []) => {
    if (x + 1 === y) return accum;
    return intervalRecursive(x + 1, y, accum.concat(x + 1));
};

intervalRecursive(1, 4) // [2, 3]
```